# Gated contact form

Tags: form

I want to create a user form that will be filled by an enduser. I'd like to store the forms data in the database.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to add a simple contact then look at [Contact Form](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/ContactForm) by Pixel & Tonic.

For anything more complex then I'd suggest looking at the [Guest Entries](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/GuestEntries) plugin also made by Pixel & Tonic. This enables you to use front-end forms to post to the database.

You may also want to look at the docs for creating [User registration forms](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/user-registration-form) on the front-end.

Answer (score 2):

There's no shortage of [form](https://straightupcraft.com/craft-plugins?q=form&) builder plugins.

I've used [FormBuilder](https://github.com/roundhouse/FormBuilder-2-Craft-CMS) and  [Formerly](https://github.com/xodigital/Formerly) on client sites.

[Sprout](https://straightupcraft.com/craft-plugins/sprout-forms) from Barrel Strength is a good pick as well if you want a paid product with commercial support.